# .psqlrc - setting keepalives_idle connection parameter

Tags: postgresql, psql

Is it possible to set `keepalives_idle` parameter in `.psqlrc` so that every connection I open uses it?

I've finally found this option and it's a remedy for my connection dropping problems.

I would really like to set it globally for all sessions I open with `psql`.

Comment: BTW there is [`PGOPTIONS` environment variable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) which you can set to something like `PGOPTIONS='-c tcp_keepalives_idle=123'`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With TCP Keepalives, it doesn't matter who sends it and who receives it. It just matters that it happened so the route isn't lost by a NAT device or closed at either end. I don't know why you'd ever want to set this on the client, as libpq offers, both methods accomplish the same thing.

## How to set keepalive transmissions from the server

*This only sets it for your session*

To set the `tcp_keepalives_idle` from the server to the client, use

```
SET tcp_keepalives_idle = 42;
```

You can put anything you want in your `~/.psqlrc` and it gets executed by psql (except under `-c` and `-x`). So append this command to the end if you want it to occur for ever psql session.

```
echo "SET tcp_keepalives_idle = 42;" >> ~/.psqlrc
```

## How do set keepalive transmissions from the client

According to [this mailing list post](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/25D3F1F4-1099-431F-9D75-1E0D56B0A383@phlo.org), you can set it on the client by typing

```
psql "host=127.0.0.1 dbname=myDB keepalives=1"
```

Comment: I don't think we're talking about the same. I want to set the `keepalives_idle` not `tcp_keepalives_idle`. It's a connection property: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/libpq-connect.html

Comment: @Kuba maybe not, what are you talking... `SET tcp_keepalives_idle`

Comment: @Kuba in libpq, the library which you use to build programs in C that connect to Postgresql, it's called `keepalives_idle`. In psql, the client that is shipped with the server, it's called [`tcp_keepalives_idle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-connection.html)

Comment: ohh I thought `tcp_keepalives_idle` you set on the server not on the client

Comment: Thanks @EvanCarrol in appears to be working! I'm a bit confused because so far I was using `psql "host=host user=user keepalives_idle=50"` so with a connection string. Does psql use libpq when a connection string is provided?

Comment: @Kuba see the update again.